# How do you pronounce "How do you" quickly?

Tags: pronunciation

It's easy to pronounce it when I speak slowly but it gets really hard when I try to speak quickly especially when it's accompanied by a long sentence.

Comment: In colloquial speech it's normally pronounced _howja_ /'hawdʒə/. This also means "How did you", since the tense markers disappear.

Comment: Or you can say "How d'ya."

Comment: It can reduce even further to just *”How ya”*.  “How do you do that” -> “How ya do that”

Comment: Right. These all occur. Everybody has their own habits about how they talk fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when not talking particularly fast, I think very few native speakers would articulate the /u/ in "do" here. Rather, it blends with the y sound, becoming /di/: **/haʊ di ju/**. This may be enough to avert the trouble you're having.

Some (especially BrE) dialects allow for eliding the middle syllable entirely, distinguished by the palatalization of /dj/ into /dʒ/: **/haʊ dʒu/**. In my (midwest AmE) dialect, this would instead be interpreted as "how'd you", i.e. "how did you".